# Усилительные наречия и наречия меры и степени

Tags: грамматика

Обе категории выражают степень. Чем они отличаются?

Answer (score 1):

В английском отличия есть, в русском нет.Наречие меры - количественный признак действия: много, мало,вдвое, втрое и т.д. Наречие степени- степень проявления того или иного признака действия:очень, почти.Наречия степени разнообразны по семантике:

а)объективная характеристика одного явления относительно другого: чуть, несколько, слегка(небольшая степень); гораздо, значительно, куда, много (значительная степень); неизмеримо•, несравненно, бесконечно (большая степень) и др.;

б) субъективная характеристика относительно субъекта речи: удивительно, изумительно, донельзя, безмерно, беспредельно, безгранично, неизмеримо, страшно, ужасно и др. Это наиболее устоявшаяся группа слов;

в) внутриструктурная характеристика части относительно целого: совсем (не), вовсе (не), совершенно (не), абсолютно (не), далеко не, отнюдь не.

Вот наречия с субъективной характеристикой усиливают признак:неизмеримо больше,ужасно много... Крайняя степень чего-то тоже усиливает: абсолютно здоровый, безгранично любил. Вероятно, имеет смысл говорить о них, но отдельно в русском языке их не выделяют, это всё наречия меры и степени.